# Why am I getting a NULL back from my JSON deserialization?

Tags: json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "dailyNews": [
    {
      "string": "D5FCF84D-B1A2-4172-9A93-E88342AA9E3C",
      "updateDate": "2019-04-24T00:00:00Z",
      "titleText": "something",
      "mainText": "sometihng ",
      "redirectionUrl": " "
    },
    {
      "string": "D5FCF84D-B1A2-4172-9A93-E88342AA9E3C",
      "updateDate": "2019-04-24T00:00:00Z",
      "titleText": "something1",
      "mainText": "sometihng2",
      "redirectionUrl": " "
    },
    {
      "string": "D5FCF84D-B1A2-4172-9A93-E88342AA9E3C",
      "updateDate": "2019-04-24T00:00:00Z",
      "titleText": "something3",
      "mainText": "sometihng4",
      "redirectionUrl": " "
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a C# class that I generated using [JSON2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/).    This class looks like this:

```
public partial class TodaysNews
{
    [JsonProperty("string")]
    public string String { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updateDate")]
    public DateTimeOffset UpdateDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("titleText")]
    public string TitleText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("ImageSrc")]
    public Uri ImageSrc { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mainText")]
    public string MainText { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("redirectionUrl")]
    public Uri RedirectionUrl { get; set; }
}

public class DailyNewsList
{
    public List<TodaysNews> transactions { get; set; }
   // public int count { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that will deserialize:

```
public static DailyNewsList FromJson(string json) => 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TodaysNews>(json, S3Reader.Converter.Settings);
```

Everything works fine; the object `TodaysNews` is initialized, however the List object `transactions` is null.   I totally don't understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DailyNewsList` class, the `transactions` property name doesn't match what is in the JSON, which is `dailyNews`.  You can fix this by decorating the `transactions` property with a `[JsonProperty]` attribute like you have done in your `TodaysNews` class:

```
public class DailyNewsList
{
    [JsonProperty("dailyNews")]
    public List<TodaysNews> transactions { get; set; }
}
```

Also, in your `FromJson` method, you should be deserializing to a `DailyNewsList` not a `TodaysNews`:

```
public static DailyNewsList FromJson(string json) => 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DailyNewsList>(json, S3Reader.Converter.Settings);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5pihJE

Comment: Thanks for your response.    Just a FYI I was building a proof of concept that a message lands on a S3 queue and I can process it.   There is something in my Json file that is the problem.  Because even with your code( that I copied from dotnetfiddle) I was getting a null back.   So, I created a class that serializes to JSON and that worked.   I don't know what wrong with my file but it was just an example so I have moved on.